# can't find module in pip after install it in google drive, using google colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

I try to install a module in google drive, so that I can keep it permanently in google colab even restart the session. Here is my code:

```
# 1. create link to google drive
import os, sys
shortcut = '/content/lib'                            
source   = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Libraries'    
os.symlink(source, shortcut)                        
sys.path.insert(0, shortcut)          

# 2. install it
!pip install --target=$shortcut playsound

# 3. try importing it
import playsound      # working ok

# 4. find it in the module list
!pip list             # cant find playsound

# 5. find it by pip show
!pip show playsound   # can't find it as well
```

and I can't find the `playsound` in #4 and #5, although I successfully import it.
my questions are:

1. how can I include it in `pip list` or `pip show`
2. and how to uninstall it? can't do it in `pip uninstall playsound` as it says it can't find the module.

Comment: Each time, you need to tell python the location of the dedicated module. It will always be available unless you turn off googledrive again. `import sys;sys.path.append('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Libraries')`

Comment: I have no problem importing it after I restart the session, I am not using `sys.path.append()` but `sys.path.insert()`. my problem is, I just can't see this module in `pip list` or `pip show playsound`, and also can't properly uninstall it by using `pip uninstall`

Comment: Don't you need `-t` for `show`, `uninstall`, and `list`, since you put the `-t,--taget` option when you install it in the right place?

Comment: ic, this can helps, thank you.